# Image Drawing on UIView

Tags: ios

I'm trying to create an application where I can draw a lot of pictures at a specific point (determined for each image) on one view. I have a coordinates where I need draw a picture, width and height of it
For example:

I have 2 billion jpeg's images. for each images I have a specific origin point and size.
In 1 second I need draw on view 20-50 images in specific point.

I have already tryid solve that in the next way:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.previewScreen.bounds.size, YES, 0);
[self.previewScreen.image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[image drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(nRect.left, nRect.top)];
UIImage *imagew = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[self.previewScreen setImage:imagew];
```

but in this solution I have a very big latency with displaying images and big CPU usage

WBR

Maxim Tartachnik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess your question is, how to make it faster?

Why draw the images using ImageContext? You could just add `UIImageView`s containing your images to your main view and position them like you need it.

Comment: If I understand clearly, I need add to my root `UIImageView` new `UIImageView` with new image. As I say previously I have many images and if for each image I'll create new `UIImageView` this may lead to memory crash

Comment: if you images wont exceed the memory limit, then neither will uiimageviews with your image. UIImageViews are only container views for your image. In your code, you are not using UIImageView but UIImage.

Comment: Sorry if I don't explain my code,
`self.previewScreen` -- this is a property 
`@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView*      previewScreen;`

Comment: So then why do you need to draw the images? Just add the image views as subview